# Revise tag prompt text to encourage fewer device tags?

Tags: support

I was preparing to ask a question and noticed that the tag prompt on main says

> at least one tag such as (2.1-eclair samsung-galaxy-s 2.3-gingerbread), max 5 tags

which means we're actively encouraging device and OS tags and is probably be giving new users the impression that the right thing to do is include the a device and OS tag with every post.

Is there a way to change that?

Comment: Good thought.  Better suggested tags are probably something like `messaging`, `wifi`, and `settings`.  (I am excluding `applications` to avoid shopping-request questions).

Comment: I don't know how that list is generated. I'm hoping it's by tag popularity. I'll tag this question "support" so that one of the Devs can answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That list is generated at website startup by picking from the top 20 tags at random.

If you see things in the list you don't like, that's a *strong* sign that elements of the site's tagging are broken.

If you need us to press the magic "make it as if this tag never existed" button, just let me know.

Comment: It's not that we don't like them. People just pick them for the wrong reason(s). We will continue to amend as necessary and educate our participants.

Comment: I don't think the tagging's broken so much as we have a feedback cycle.  `2.1-eclair` is a useful tag, so there are a lot of questions about it, so new users see it and use it inappropriately, so there are a lot of questions about it, so new users see it and use it inappropriately ... etc.

Comment: Is it worth adding to the tag wiki some brief guidance on when it's useful to use?

Comment: @foley yes, that is *specifically* one of the suggestions at http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/ see #4 in that list

Answer (score 2):

Given Jeff's answer & response to my comment, and the fact that I can't see that any of our tag wikis currently ["Provide basic guidance on when to use the tag"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/) (though they do define what the tag means), I'd suggest we start with this.

The Device/OS tags are a great example - can we first define when it is appropriate/useful to apply these tags, add some guidance to the tag wikis and see if that makes any difference?

Comment: Actually, the WIFI tag has decent usage guidance: http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/wifi/info

Comment: Good point. I've been writing a lot of the tag wikis and I actually contemplated sticking a standard line on the device and OS pages. I'll start a separate discussion for that.

Comment: Yes, good idea. Even if it doesn't change usage, it will at least help us decide if we have a problem / how big it is if we can define what correct usage is in the first place!