# Standard text for device, OS tag wikis?

Tags: discussion, tags

Based on these two discussions:

[Revise tag prompt text to encourage fewer device tags?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/447/revise-tag-prompt-text-to-encourage-fewer-device-tags)

[Why did someone pull the device tag from this question?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396/why-did-someone-pull-the-device-tag-from-this-question)

I'm trying to come up with good standard lines for the device and OS tag tips. I think we want to say:

"Add a device tag only if your question is genuinely specific to your make and model!"

"Add an OS tag only if your question is genuinely specific to the OS you're running."

Does that seem about right? I'm happy to go through and add that, but I'd like some feedback first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like "Only add a device or OS tag if your question is truly *about* your make and model, not just related!" would be even clearer.

Comment: Sounds about right. I'll make the change since no one else seems to have weighed in.